# How to enable subversion merge tracking

Tags: svn, merge, tracking, merge-tracking

How do I enable svn client to start saving svn:mergeinfo property.

My client is v1.6.5 and the server runs 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Server version 1.5 should be able to save mergeinfo data.

Perhaps your repository was created with much older version. Try:

```
svnadmin upgrade /path/to/repository
```